# Hibernate strategies fetch multiple tables offline?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, parent-child, fetch

Sounds crazy but here is the story.

Background:

- Imagine that our DB look like: Company has n Employee which has spouse and children. Employee also has cars which have tires...so on and so forth...
- Our application provides both Web and Desktop UI. So users want to load data from several tables for working offline on desktop. For example: loading around 1000 Company to desktop to work on.
- Data volume is somehow big, vary from thousands records to sometimes hundred thousand ones. But the data to be loaded offline is not that big only few thousands.

Current architecture:

- We are using [HibernateAssembler from Adobe ADEP4.6](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/AEPDeveloperGuide/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811f00f6f4da-7fffUpdate.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811f00f7045b-7f55Update), quite similar to a DAO, e.g for each entity we have one Assembler. But the access to Hibernate is very limited.
- For Web, we use LAZY Loading, so far so good.
- For AIR desktop, we are trying many options

Options for AIR desktop, note that Entity are all marked as LAZY, we are thinking about 1 of the following options:

1. Using "fetch join" in named hql: Loading Company, employee, car, tire together in one hql
2. Load each table individually then match them manually.
3. Using EAGER FETCH with BatchSize ?!! Hard to control
4. Give up Hibernate and go back to huge JDBC queries.

Please give us your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you've got multiple 1-N relationships, the returned ResultSet will contain so much redundant data that Hibernate will be too slow to process in my experience.
2. I'd go for this either using Hibernate or plain SQL. Actually Hibernate can do this for a certain degree, by annotating your relationships with @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT).
   For example, when you are retrieving some companies based on a condition, the following SQLs will run:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM company WHERE condition
   SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee.company_id IN (SELECT id FROM company WHERE condition)
   ```

   Note though that this only works efficiently in certain databases. If it is not performing well, consider #3.
3. I've tried BatchSize in such cases and it improved performance somewhat, but option #2 was better.
4. It boils down to the SQL run. If that is efficient, Hibernate usually will not add that much overhead (only the overhead of object creation, keeping all objects in memory, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I am still working on it. I am happy with your answer, but let's see others think

Comment: After many tests, we decided to go for :

@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

It saves alot of performance. Then depending on the specific case, it can be LAZY or EAGER. Usage in combination with #1 is good too

Comment: Regarding option 2, what do you mean by "certain degree"? Does this mean it will not work in certain scenarios?

Comment: It will definitely work, however it may not give best performance for the specific database (IN clause with subquery is not always fast, depends on DB)